# How to test the function which runs the server

Tags: go

I have a struct called `Server` and it has this method:

```golang
func (s *Server) Run(addr string) error {
    return http.ListenAndServe(addr, s)
}
```

Here is one of the ways that I usually test this kind of functions:

```golang
func TestServer_Run(t *testing.T) {
    srv := NewServer()

    go srv.Run(":2376")

    // Give server sometime to start
    time.Sleep(20*time.Millisecond)

    // Send some request to server and test the result.
}
```

I don't want to test the endpoints and I just want to see if server runs properly.
But I didn't find this way very nice because I wait for 20ms and the server might start earlier and I'm wasting some time in here.
Also server starts faster but I have to sleep for 20ms so I'm sure that server has started and now I can start using the server.

What is the best way of testing functions like this? Actually How to avoid `time.Sleep()`?

Comment: Your function does nothing but call a function from the stdlib that already has its own tests. What is the value of testing this function?

Comment: Actually it does other things but I removed them for readability.

Comment: What I typically do is rather than use `http.ListenAndServe`, use an instance of `http.Server` (which would likely be a field of your `Server` type), with a function that does nothing but call `Server.ListenAndServe` so that testing it is irrelevant.

Comment: Your question also seems to give some conflicting information - you say "I don't want to test the endpoints" but also "now I can start using the server" and "Send some request to server and test the result" - so are you testing endpoints or not? For testing endpoints you generally don't want to actually start the server, just call the handlers directly using requests from `net/http/httptest`.

Comment: Yeah I know I can test them with httptest. By sending requests I mean I want to check healthiness of my server and I don't want to test the result I got from endpoints. for example when I call my product api i dont want to test that if my paginations is working or not, I just wanna know I can get responses after I call `Run` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the TCP listener first, after that you can make the HTTP request while the server is starting. The request will be processed as soon as the server is ready.

Actually another issue is how to stop the server at the end of the test.

Below is an example of how to achieve both:

```golang
func TestServer_Run(t *testing.T) {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:3000")
    require.NoError(t, err)

    r := http.NewServeMux()
    r.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, _ = w.Write([]byte("Hello!"))
    })
    server := &http.Server{Handler: r}
    defer server.Close()
    go func() {
        if err := server.Serve(l); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    res, err := http.Get("http://localhost:3000")
    require.NoError(t, err)

    body, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    require.Equal(t, "Hello!", string(body))
}
```